# How to include tags names in Contentful API object

Tags: nuxt.js, contentful

I'm trying to get attached to an object tags list with tags names, and couldn't find any documentation how to do this. Right now my object looks like this using `await $contentful.getEntry(route.params.id)`:

```json
{
  "metadata": {
    "tags": [
      {
        "sys": {
          "type": "Link",
          "linkType": "Tag",
          "id": "nuxtJs"
        }
      },
      {
        "sys": {
          "type": "Link",
          "linkType": "Tag",
          "id": "vueJs"
        }
      },
      {
        "sys": {
          "type": "Link",
          "linkType": "Tag",
          "id": "vuex"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "sys": {...},
  "fields": {
    "name": "Bla",
    "subtitle": "bla",
    "url": "https://www.bla.com/",
    "type": "portfolio",
    "date": "2021-03-03",
    "aboutClient": "Bla",
    "objective": "Bla"
   }
}
```

Here `metadata` includes tags, but doesn't include tag names, for example tag name for `nuxtJs` is `Nuxt.js`.

Is there any way to also include tags names? How I can do it using https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js SDK?